# How I can find any element in XML by matching via pattern attribute and attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find elements in XML with attribute which contains in naming login or username and attribute value contains more then 15 chars.
Probably for first case I need to apply pattern

```
.*(login|username).*
```

and for second

```
^.{15,}$
```

I'm really trying to cover such cases in more common way. I need to find such kind of rows in XML.

```
<props>
    <prop key="foo.bar.login">long_value_with_more_than_15_chars</prop>
    <prop name="username.foo.bar" value="long_value__with_more_than_15_chars"/>
    <prop foo.login.bar="long_value_with_more_than_15_chars"/>
</props>
```

Length of foo.bar.login, username.foo.bar and foo.login.bar doesn't matter.
So for this purposes I need to use XPath but I cannot understand how to apply patterns.

Comment: What version of XPath do you use? Please show a complete example of an input document.

Comment: XPath 2.0 http://pastebin.com/qG0Ln38i So for now I don't know how to cover first case.

Comment: First case will be found in my solution, because of the _login_ within the value of the attribute `key`. Do you want to find it, cause of the text within the element `prop`?

Comment: Login or username can be attribute or attribute value AND text/value should be with min length 15. So for example http://pastebin.com/8qCWm01U should return 0 rows, cause length of string "short_login" less then 15.

Comment: please take note of my edited answer. otherwise please give input and/or accept as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't edit the question from one to another given info. Please clarify your expectations.**

**Xpath 2.0:**

```
//*[@*[matches(name(),"login|username") or matches(., "login|username")]][(@value and string-length(@value) gt 15) or string-length() gt 15]
```

**Xpath 1.0:**

```
//*[@*[contains(name(),"login") or contains(name(), "username") or contains(.,"login") or contains(., "username")]][(@value and string-length(@value) > 15) or string-length() > 15]
```

**Explanation:**

Search in *attributename* as well in *value* of attribute for strings `login` and `username` or value of attribute `value` is greater than 15 chars or value of node is greater than 15 chars.

If you like, give it a up. Otherwise please explain your problems with the results.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
//*[@*[(contains(.,'login') or contains(.,'username')) and string-length() > 15]]
```

Comment: it's cover second and third cases. can u help me with first case <prop key="foo.bar.login">long_login</prop> ?

Comment: dont you want that only attribute that contains more than 15 chars ?

Comment: in this case we need to check text length

Answer (score 1):

for xpath 1 it might read

```
//*[@*[(contains(name(),'login') or contains(name(),'username'))
       and string-length(.) &gt; 15]
```